# inheritance import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-modules

I looked at similar questions/answers but they are different from my question or my setup.

I've a class B that extends class A and writing a test for the class B.

### src folder

**src/a/A.js**

```
export default class A {
    // implementation
}
```

**src/b/B.js**

```
import A from "../a/A" // -> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

export default class B extends A {
    constructor() {

    }
}
```

### test folder

```
describe("BTest", function(){

    let assert = require("assert");

    describe("testConstructor", function(){
        let B = require("../src/b/B");

        let b = new B();

        assert(b != null)

    });

});
```

Comment: in `src/b/classB`code, isn't that because you're importing a wrong file `import A from "../a/A"` where it should be `import A from "../a/classA"`?

Comment: sorry typo, fixed the filename typo

Comment: How exactly are you running this code? What node version are you using? (I will assume that your tag was a typo and you meant node.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be running in a node environment. Node doesn't support import/export. You’ll need to either use `require` and `module.exports` or transpile your code using Babel.

Comment: yes this seems to be true, I need to make this work for a browser and actually accommodate later for nodeJS. so the first thing I need to get into Babel